# Recreating Sketchfab's "ambient environment" with threejs - multiple CubeMaps?

Tags: three.js

I am trying to recreate Sketchfab's "ambient environment" feature in threejs.

[see sketchfab background settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voYCJ.jpg)

I want my model in threejs to show a traditional environment map (360 picture of a location), but I want the scene to show a blurred, ambient image as the environement.

I tried loading two cubetextures and applying one to the envMap of the model, and the other to the scene.background:

```
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load( "../../image/download/img1.jpg", function ( texture ) {
        texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
        texture.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
        var cubemapGenerator = new THREE.EquirectangularToCubeGenerator( texture, { resolution: 512 } );
        var cubeMapTexture = cubemapGenerator.update( renderer );
        var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( cubeMapTexture );
        pmremGenerator.update( renderer );
        var pmremCubeUVPacker = new THREE.PMREMCubeUVPacker( pmremGenerator.cubeLods );
        pmremCubeUVPacker.update( renderer );
        envMapCubeRenderTarget = pmremCubeUVPacker.CubeUVRenderTarget;
        var envMap = envMapCubeRenderTarget ? envMapCubeRenderTarget.texture : null;


        texture.dispose();
        pmremGenerator.dispose();
        pmremCubeUVPacker.dispose();

        object.material.envMap = envMap

        var loader2 = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        loader2.load( "../../image/download/img2.jpg", function ( texture ) {
            texture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
            texture.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
            var cubemapGenerator = new THREE.EquirectangularToCubeGenerator( texture, { resolution: 512 } );
            envMapBackground = cubemapGenerator.renderTarget;
            scene.background = envMapBackground; //old = texture
            scene.background.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
        });

     });
```

When I try to use two cubemaps, my scene just renders a blank background...

Comment: Try this: `scene.background = new THREE.CubemapGenerator( renderer ).fromEquirectangular( texture, options );` three.js r.105

Comment: Hey, thanks.  That worked!  But why?  Is THREE.CubemapGenerator new in r.105?

Comment: It is not new. Well for one thing, you are failing to call `cubemapGenerator.update( renderer );`